# Exim4 - temporarily freeze outgoing emails from specific user

Tags: debian, access-control-list, exim

I need to temporarily freeze outgoing emails from specific sender with exim4. The sender logs in with remote SMTP (i.e. over TCP/IP).

What I want to do is to freeze (but not deny) all his emails so I can check the queue and either allow or disallow further processing.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to make the following changes to your `exim.conf` file:

In the main configuration section, make sure that you have enabled the `acl_smtp_mail` control as follows:

```
acl_smtp_mail = acl_check_mail
```

Be sure to change `acl_check_mail` to the actual name of your access control list that handles `acl_smtp_mail`

Then, in the `acl_check_rcpt` ACL configuration section, create a new rule:

```
accept   condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/freezelist_sender_addresses}{1}{0}}
         control   = freeze/no_tell
```

Save the config file. Now create the file `/etc/exim/freezelist_sender_addresses` and place all your sender addresses which need to be frozen into this file, one address per line. Make sure you set the correct permissions on this file so that Exim can read it.

All emails sent from the addresses in the `/etc/exim/freezelist_sender_addresses` will now be accepted into the queue (provided they pass the other ACLs) and then automatically frozen by Exim.

To unfreeze these messages, run this command, replacing user@domain.tld with the address of the sender whose mail has been frozen:

```
exiqgrep -i -f user@domain.tld | xargs exim -Mt
```

Comment: To freeze mail sent locally from web apps I had to put the rule in the `acl_not_smtp` acl.

Answer (score 0):

Does this command can be used to unfreeze by email ID as well or is different command?

I mean, if I want to unfreeze by email ID, could this be used?

exiqgrep -i -f 1pUg6E-0003Dt-83 | xargs exim -Mt