# Exim 4.63 - temporarily freeze outgoing emails from specific user sent by horde/roundcube

Tags: email, exim, roundcube, horde

I am following this solution 
Exim4 - temporarily freeze outgoing emails from specific user ([Exim4 - temporarily freeze outgoing emails from specific user](https://serverfault.com/questions/265963/exim4-temporarily-freeze-outgoing-emails-from-specific-user))

I am able to get email freeze from specific sender, but only when I send it from console through "telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 25". Solution is not working when I send emails from Horde/Roundcube and any Desktop Client.

Please guide me where I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the acl_not_smtp acl

```
acl_not_smtp = acl_not_smtp
```

Then create the rule under that acl

```
acl_not_smtp:
   accept   condition = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/etc/exim/freezelist_sender_addresses}{1}{0}}
         control   = freeze/no_tell
   accept
```